# Import PostgreSQL dump into SQL Server - data type errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, ssis

I have some data which was dumped from a PostgreSQL database (allegedly, using pg_dump) which needs to get imported into SQL Server.
While the data types are ok, I am running into an issue where there seems to be a placeholder for a NULL. I see a backslash followed by an uppercase N in many fields. Below is a snippet of the data, as viewed from within Excel. Left column has a Boolean data type, and the right one has an integer as the data type

[image: Snippet of the data, as viewed from within Excel. Left column has a Boolean data type, and the right one has an integer as the data type]

Some of these are supposed to be of the Boolean datatype, and having two characters in there is most certainly not going to fly.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Import via dirty read - keeping whatever datatypes SSIS decided each field had; to no avail. There were error messages about truncation on all of the boolean fields.
2. Creating a table for the data based on the correct data types, though this was more fun... I needed to do the same as in the dirty read, as the source would otherwise not load properly. There was also a need to transform the data into the correct data type for insertion into the destination data source; yet, I am getting truncation issues, when it most certainly shouldn't be.
   Here is a sample expression in my derived column transformation editor:
   `(DT_BOOL)REPLACE(observation,"\\N","")`
   The data type should be Boolean.

Any suggestion would be really helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just replace the `\N` directly in the file using a text editor of your choice?

Comment: @cha, If this were a one-time deal, I would have done a find/replace right away; however, if the data looks good, this may turn into a long-term automated process in which I, obviously, cannot do what you suggested. I should have put this point into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to circumvent the SSIS rules in order to get my data into my tables without an error, I took the quick-and-dirty approach.
The solution which worked for me was to have the source data read each column as if it were a string, and the destination table had all fields be of the datatype VARCHAR. This destination table will be used as a staging table, once in SS, I can manipulate as needed.

Thank you @cha for your input.